# Inline-block - Alignment Issue When Browser Resized

Tags: html, css

I have a max-width wrapper, within it are four boxes of a fixed width and height. When the browser window is reduced, the boxes fall inline and centered within the container, but the alignment is slightly out, as if there's a small left margin.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2fyrh7/

If I remove "text-align:center;" from #boxcontainer it clears up the alignment issue, but then the boxes won't be center-aligned inside the container which I require when the browser window is reduced.

If I remove ".box:last-child" then that also solves the alignment issue, but then all four boxes won't be inline when the browser window is >960px.

I appreciate any help/suggestions on where I'm going wrong.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
#boxcontainer {
    width:100%;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    font-size:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.box {
    width:225px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
.box:last-child {
        margin-right:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="boxcontainer">

        <div class="box">
                <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
                <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
                <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
                <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to your box class.

If you want to solve this on a specific media device use media query.

Comment: If I use float:left instead of an inline-block, then the boxes aren't center aligned inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-right:0px;` on the the last div is causing the spacing issue. If i remove that, it seems to be fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ve2fyrh7/2/.

Comment: If I remove the margin-right, then all 4 boxes don't fit inside the container when the browser window is >960px.